# Jquery datetimepicker in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to implement the jQuery datetimepicker in my ASP.NET webpage.

1. Followed the link http://www.projectcodegen.com/JQueryDateTimePicker.aspx
2. I am trying to implement the sample in my code.
3. I did add the js and the css files to my application.

The pop-up calender with time is not displayed when I run the application.

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="jquery.ui.datetimepicker.css" type="text/css" />   
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.datetimepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.datetimepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){           
        $('TextBox1').datetimepicker();
        });
</script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>        
       <input type="text" id="TextBox1" />        
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In jQuery, to select elements by id you do it like this:

```
$('#TextBox1').datetimepicker();
```

See the documentation on [ID selectors](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and [class selectors](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery ui comes with an extremely easy to use datepicker. There are excellent easy to follow examples for every control.

Here's the link to the demo/documentation of the DatePicker:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

To use jQuery ui you need to following references. I don't see these in your code.

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/themename/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The scripts listed in the OP code sample could be the jquery ui css/js files but the naming is not consistent with the defaults of those files. So I assume they are not the same.

Comment: Thank for your time .i am looking for the datetimepicker not just the date picker.Its working fine with the syntax $('#TextBox1').datetimepicker();,which fixes my problem in the code