# Date in textbox in dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: asp.net, date

I am a beginner with C# and am having some problems with DateTime.
I do not want to use 3 separate dropdowns or textboxes for date. But I still want to be able to put restrict the user input to the format of the date (dd/mm/yyyy). How can I do that?

Note: I am just a learner so please explain whatever code you write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You can use javascript to restrict your date feild.

See below my code

Your textbox in aspx page ,

`<asp:Textbox ID="txtDate" runat="server" />`

and use javascript like below

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function ValidateDateOf() {
    DayObj = new Date();
    var txtdate =  document.getElementById('<%=txtDate.ClientID %>').value;
    var arr = txtdate.split("/");
    var leapday = arr[0];
    var leapmonth = arr[1];
    var leapyear = arr[2];

    var CurDate = DayObj.getDate();
    var CurYear = DayObj.getFullYear();
    var CurMonth = DayObj.getMonth();

    if (leapday == '') {
        alert('day Field is required');
        return false;
    }
    if (leapmonth == '') {
        alert('month Field is required');
        return false;
    }
    if (leapyear == '') {
        alert('year Field is required');
        return false;
    }
    if (parseInt(leapday) > 29) {
        alert('invalid date');
         return false;
    }
    if (!isleap(leapyear)) {
        if (parseInt(leapday) > 28) {
            alert('invalid date');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}

function isleap(leapyear) {
    var yr = leapyear;
    if ((parseInt(yr) % 4) == 0) {
        if (parseInt(yr) % 100 == 0) {
            if (parseInt(yr) % 400 != 0) {
                return false;
            }
            if (parseInt(yr) % 400 == 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (parseInt(yr) % 100 != 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if ((parseInt(yr) % 4) != 0) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [ASP.NET AJAX Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx) it has a sample MaskedEdit box which should accomplish what you are looking for.

alternativly you could use a validator with regex to check the format, a second validator to check the date is real (ie leap year issues).

But I think a much cleaner UI way is to use a MaskedEdit system along with the validator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AJAX Control Toolkit's CalendarExtender.

Answer (score 0):

[Use a jquery datetime picker.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366502/jquery-datetimepicker-in-asp-net)

[Implement jQuery datetime picker](http://forums.asp.net/t/1661071.aspx/1)